# Game dev Unity 2d game: Problem with code and gameObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, game-engine, game-development

I have a question. so i want to make the player destroy when he hits a certain sprite. Its like a void in Minecraft. It keeps saying the following: *error CS0103: The name 'Player"does not exist in the current context*. Can someone help me?
This is the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Void : MonoBehaviour
{   
    
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
       gameObject = Player;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
        {   
            
              if(col.gameObject.CompareTag("Obstacle")) //If thing hit is tagged "Obstacle"
              {
                      Destroy(gameObject); //Then destroy the player
              }
         }
}
```

}[The unity screen with important things i guess.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCu0M.png)
p.s. my englis isnt that good, sorry for that!

It tried many things, i hope someone can help me...

Comment: you should get the player first in start method by using
gameobject = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
and assign the player a tag by going in player inspector.

Comment: Is this code put on your player?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the void script attach to player,
then you can destroy directly.

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
        {   
           if(col.gameObject.CompareTag("Obstacle")) //If thing hit is tagged "Obstacle"
              {
                      Destroy(this.gameObject); //Then destroy the player
              }
         }
```